# nhibernate querying over other query results

Tags: sql, nhibernate, queryover

Hello i'm trying to get all users which have had payments at least 6 months over the given period (which must be a year). I've written SQL which works fine, but i have difficulties trying to convert it to nhibernate.

SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(UserId) AS paidMonthsCount, UserId FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT UserId,
            YEAR(PayDate) as _year,
            MONTH(PayDate) as _month
    FROM Payments
    WHERE PayDate >= '2014-04-02T00:00:00' AND PayDate < '2015-04-02T23:59:00'
)result GROUP BY result.UserId
```

i have converted inner SQL:

```
var subQuery = Session.QueryOver(() => paymentAlias)
                    .SelectList(list => list
                                        .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property<VelferdPayment>(p => p.Client.Id)).WithAlias(() => userWithHelp.Id))
                                        .Select(p => p.AssignmentYear).WithAlias(() => userWithHelp.AssignmentDate)
                               )
                    .WhereRestrictionOn(p => p.AssignmentDate)
                    .IsBetween(parameters.FromDate)
                    .And(parameters.ToDate);
```

which selects the distinct part and i have the other part which is selecting from result:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver(() => userWithHelp).
                    SelectList(list => list
                                       .SelectCount(p=> p.Id).WithAlias(()=> userWithHelpCount.Count)
                                       .SelectGroup(p => p.Id).WithAlias(() => userWithHelpCount.Id)

                               )
                   .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<UserWithHelpCount>())
                   .List<UserWithHelpCount>();
```

How can i queryover the subQuery results or is it possible to write single request to SQL. Working for a long time please help.

Comment: FROM part of any NHibernate query is defined by your mapping. It could be only table, view or subselect which is related to entity. No custom FROM blocks, unless you will use raw SQL with CreateSQLQuery()

Comment: so my SubQuery is sub select as I understand so can i select from subQuery ?

Comment: FROM could will be always content of the `<class>` mapping related to `table="some.table"` or `table="some.view"` or to `subselect="some SELECT statement"`. The **mapping** *(just mentioned)* is the content of the FROM. Does it help? is it clear now?

Comment: Not really, its not clear what should i do next? Is it possible to write my SQL in one query or i need two of them?

Comment: Tried to give you some view on it and hints in my answer. Hope it helps. Anyhow, you should try to read more about NHibernate and ORM in general. It is not about SQL generator. It is about entities and their relations. For such complex queries as you have we should use some reporting or `CreateSQLQuery()` API as mentioned in my answer. Hope it helps now

Answer (score 0):

In general, with NHibernate we can only (or mainly) query Entities, not TABLES. Other words, we firstly map tables or views or even some `<subselect>`s into entities. The below mapping of the `User` *(C# object `User`)*

```
<class name="user" table="[dbo].[user_table]" ...
```

Will allow us to create query over C# `User`.

```
session.QueryOver<User>()...
```

Behind the scene it will generate FROM clause, which will contain the content of `table` attribute, i.e. `FROM [dbo].[user_table]`

That's it. There is no other way how to set the generated FROM clause. Just by mapping.

But there is a way which allow us to use existing ADO.NET connection to create custom query and even convert its result to some entity, or DTO. It is `CreateSQLQuery()` API:

#### [17.1.5. Returning non-managed entities](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#d0e11364)

> It is possible to apply an `IResultTransformer` to native sql queries. Allowing it to e.g. return non-managed entities.

```
sess.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(CatDTO)))
```

> This query specified:
>
> - the SQL query string
> - a result transformer
>
> The above query will return a list of CatDTO which has been instantiated and injected the values of NAME and BIRTHNAME into its corresponding properties or fields.

So, we can use native SQL SELECT statements to get any results. We can even create some custom DTO and let NHibernate to transform result into them...